# How to use get_planning_pipeline_id?

Tags: python, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How should I use [get_planning_pipeline_id](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/f72930cfec0e5293fd488dd2e9fedb1419b91bc3/moveit_commander/src/moveit_commander/move_group.py#L540)? It is not clear what I should input as planning_pipeline, an example in python would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381866/how-to-use-get_planning_pipeline_id?/) by [lorepieri](https://answers.ros.org/users/60501/lorepieri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2021-07-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to set both the `planning_pipeline_id` and the `planner_id`. You can easily check the available pipelines and the planners of each pipeline in the RViz Motion Planning plugin, in the `Context` tab.

Example Python code:

```
group = moveit_commander.MoveGroupCommander("your_planning_group")
group.set_planning_pipeline_id("pilz_industrial_motion_planner")
group.set_planner_id("LIN")
[...]
group.set_pose_target(your_pose)
group.go()
```

If only one pipeline is available, you should regenerate your moveit_config package.

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2021-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lorepieri](https://answers.ros.org/users/60501/lorepieri/) on 2021-07-06**:
What about the getter (get_planning_pipeline_id)? Why it requires planning_pipeline as parameter, if I just want to get? Is it perhaps a bug in the implementation?

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-07-06**:
Yes, that's a bug. It will be fixed shortly.

**Comment by [lorepieri](https://answers.ros.org/users/60501/lorepieri/) on 2021-07-07**:
Got it, thanks. I'm opening an issue on moveit to track this.

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-07-09**:
It's fixed.